# I want to open my pdf object of Teamcenter Active Workspace (AWS) only in view window of explorer browser through link, how can I configure URL?

Tags: javascript, pdf, webclient, pdf.js, teamcenter

I have TC Active Workspace version after 4.0 (AWS) URL Link of my organisation like this: http://:Port/#/com.siemens.splm.clientfx.tcui.xrt.showObject?uid= .

I want to open a PDF in Browser View only. My object contains a PDF as an attachment. How can I open PDF in View mode in the browser **only through URL**??

When I open a link through the above-specified link, it opens an object as well as a view of pdf but I want to open only PDF view, instead of other information of the object.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to view data of the PDF and you want to view only PDF when you open it from active workspace, crate a separate stylesheet for the PDF and add viewer content only in the stylehseet. Add below snippet then it will show only PDF viewer.

```
<page titleKey="tc_xrt_Overview">
    <section titleKey="tc_xrt_Preview">
        <inject type="dataset" src="Awp0GalleryViewer" module="js/aw-include.directive"/>
    </section>
</page>
```